# Connect Samsung tablet to ethernet and also to PC/laptop?

Tags: adb, samsung, usb, ethernet

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab Active Pro (SM-T545) tablet. I'd like to connect it to the ethernet using an adapter having an RJ45 port. I would also like to connect the tablet to my laptop (in this case MacBook Air) so that I can access the logs.

I tried using the Type-C Hub (from [UGREEN](https://www.amazon.com.au/UGREEN-Docking-Station-Ethernet-Delivery/dp/B093FKT9BF/)) that has an RJ45 port and the tablet connected to the ethernet successfully. However, when I try to connect my laptop using a Type-C to Type-C cable and later Type-A (from hub) to Type-C (to laptop), nothing happens on the tablet and laptop.

Is there any way I can connect the tablet to ethernet for the internet and also to my laptop to get the logs?

Note: The wireless option is not possible as the connection is very unstable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To talk to the Ethernet adapter, the Android device has to switch its USB chip to host mode (USB OTG). The Android device becomes the USB master managing the USB bus, and the Ethernet adapter will work as a USB slave (usually USB Ethernet adapters can only work as a USB slave).

The USB chip in the PC is always acting in USB host mode (as USB master).
If you are connecting two USB chips both in host mode, it will not work, as in USB, there can be only one host (master) and multiple clients (slaves).

The only way I see to get a wired network connection and connect the Android device to your PC at the same time would be to use reverse tethering via adb.

Comment: I managed a workaround by getting a new access point. The connection from it is very stable and I connected the tablet wirelessly to the AP and through wire to my laptop. It solves the issue. Thanks for the advice.